# Is it allowed to store billing address for merchants SAQ A merchants? (PCI DSS)

Tags: encryption, tls, public-key-infrastructure, storage, standards

I know there are many limitations for data storing and processing by PCI DSS. Some of them are explained here. https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pdfs/pci_fs_data_storage.pdf
But I can't find any info about storing customers' billing addresses. Is this means that PCI allows it for any merchants / service providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PCI DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2-1.pdf) concerns itself with the following pieces of data:

[image: PCI DSS protected data fields]

Except insofar as it might include Customer Name, billing address is not PCI protected data, and there are no PCI requirements around storage, encryption, or lack thereof.  Instead, that data is PII, and should be protected in line with whatever PII standards apply to your locality.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks for clarification!